# Methods not working

Tags: c#, winforms

In my main form, I am running this:

```
this.disableForm();
btnAbort.Enabled = true;
```

disableForm is an extension method for Form in my program defined as the following:

```
public static void disableForm(this Form f)
{
    foreach (Control c in f.Controls)
    {
        f.Enabled = false;
    }

    f.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
}
```

The problem is that the next command `btnAbort.Enabled = true;` doesn't do anything.

It works if I put the code directly in the method and not call `disableForm()`. Why is this happening? Does it have something to do with threads?

Comment: You can't modify UI elements from a non-UI thread, if that's what you're asking

Comment: Where in my question did I mention this was not a UI thread?

Comment: You should be more thorough about what you mean by "Does this have something to do with threads" then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
f.Enabled = false;
```

Should be

```
c.Enabled = false;
```

The problem is because you are accidentally disabling your entire form.

Comment: Like rory said, first you're disabling your entire form, and then you're enabling one button. Of course this button will not be enabled then, since the container (in this case, your form) is disabled.

Comment: Single letter variable names are likely to cause confusion.

Comment: What do you men by S l v n a l t c c?

Comment: Agree with @Rory-McCrossan and want to note that you can't to enable control that is child of disabled control. Be attentive to not place your button into, for example, group box. For this case you need to write more flexible method to disable form and another method to enable one control - that will enable all parents of this control.

Comment: @AlexanderBurov - I guess recursively enabling each parent should do?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void disableForm(this Form f)
    {
        foreach (Control c in f.Controls)
        {
            //f.Enabled = false;
              c.Enabled = false;
         }

        f.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    }
```